# How to add text to span tags consecutively one letter at a time using forEach() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have three span tags, and I need to add some text to each in such a way so that it looks like it is being typed out onto the screen. I am using forEach() to loop through each span tag and running a function which is supposed to add each letter one at a time to each span tag consecutively.

However, forEach is adding each letter to all three span tags all at the same time. I only get the desired 'typing' effect on the last span tag once the other two have had all their letters added.

How can I adjust forEach so that it looks like the text is being typed out onto the screen? Please note the text has to be in individual span tags for styling purposes.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/stephTheMachine/Lowajv02/17/)

```js
let delay = 500;
let currentChar = 1;
let idArr = ["firstSpan", "secondSpan", "thirdSpan"];
let textArr = ["heading ", ": ", "'My Book Title'"];

idArr.forEach((item, index) => {

    let text = textArr[index];

    function type() {

        document.getElementById(item).innerHTML = text.substr(0, currentChar);

        currentChar++;

        if (currentChar > text.length) {

            console.log('text length check running')

            currentChar = 1

        } else {

            setTimeout(type, delay);

        }

    }

    type();
})
```

```css
.cursor {
  color: black;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span id="firstSpan"></span>
  <span id="secondSpan"></span>
  <span id="thirdSpan"></span>
</span>
<span class="cursor">|</span>
```

Comment: You need to add the text *heading:* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work fine except that you have to move `currentChar` inside the foreach as it belong to item

See example blow

```js
let delay = 500;

let idArr = ["firstSpan", "secondSpan", "thirdSpan"];
let textArr = ["heading ", ": ", "'My Book Title'"];
let currentIndex = 0;

   
let currentChar = 1;
function type() {
let text = textArr[currentIndex];
var item =    idArr[currentIndex];
document.getElementById(item).innerHTML = text.substr(0, currentChar);
    
currentChar ++;

   if(currentChar > text.length) { 

        console.log('text length check running')
    
        currentChar = 1
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex < idArr.length) 
            setTimeout(type, delay);
       
    } else {
    
       setTimeout(type, delay);
       
    }

   } 

   type();
```

```css
.cursor {
  color: black;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span id="firstSpan"></span>
  <span id="secondSpan"></span>
  <span id="thirdSpan"></span>
</span>
<span class="cursor">|</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Alen. Toma - that makes sense. However, I need the first span tag to type out and complete its text first before the second one starts, then once the second one has typed out its text then the third one starts. At the moment they are all starting to type at the same time. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Yes sorry about that i made and update, feel free to test it

Comment: Brilliant Alen.Toma that is just what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I can't resist...

```js
const delay = async(ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  ,   spanN = document.querySelectorAll('#sp3 span')
  ,   txtArr = ['heading ', ': ', 'My Book Title' ]
  ;
async function* LettersSpanGen(aT)
  {
  let SpLt = aT.reduce((r,c,sp)=>[...r,...[...c].map(lt=>({sp,lt}))],[])
  yield* SpLt
  }
(async function()
  {
  for await (let {sp,lt} of LettersSpanGen( txtArr )) 
    {
    spanN[sp].textContent += lt
    await delay(500)
    }
  }
)();
```

```css
#sp3 span:last-of-type {
  --blinkColor : darkblue;
  color        : var(--blinkColor);
  font-weight  : bold;
  animation    : 1s blink step-end infinite;
  }
@keyframes blink {
  from, to { color: transparent;       }
  50%      { color: var(--blinkColor); }
  }
```

```html
<div id="sp3">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span>|</span>
</div>
```

Any questions ?

Comment: Is there a name for that formatting style?

Comment: @Ouroborus yes, WhiteSmith style, plus personnal addings

Comment: @MisterJojo thanks so much for this alternate solution. I would never have thought of approaching it like this. This is really great - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
(()=>{
  const delay = 500;
  const elements = ['firstSpan','secondSpan','thirdSpan'].map(
    v => document.getElementById(v)
  );
  const contents = ["heading ", ": ", "'My Book Title'"]
  const idx = [0, 0];
  const length = [
    () => contents[idx[1]].length,
    () => contents.length,
  ];
  const doUpdate = () => {
    elements[idx[1]].innerText += contents[idx[1]][idx[0]];
    if(idx.every((v,i) => ++idx[i] >= length[i]() ? !(idx[i]=0) : 0)) return;
    setTimeout(doUpdate, delay);
  };
  doUpdate();
})();
```

Comment: This is a great solution - awesome to see other ways to solve this! Thank you Ouroborus!